# createElement shows as text node

Tags: javascript, dom

Why would

`console.log(document.createElement("p").appendChild(document.createTextNode("some text")));`

return

`<TextNode textContent="some text">`

in Firebug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you chained the `appendChild` function to your `createElement` and whatever it returns will be the last return value. Your `console.log` statement logs that last return value.

[.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) returns the appended child